# Trying to connect to accdb database with c# and .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, oledb, ms-access

I keep getting an exception when I try to fill the adapter and i can't figure out why.  Here is my code.  Thank you very much in advance for any information!

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private OleDbConnection connection;
    private OleDbCommand command;
    private OleDbDataAdapter adapter;
    private DataSet dataset;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        connection = new OleDbConnection();
        command = new OleDbCommand();
        adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        dataset = new DataSet();

        connection.ConnectionString =
            @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:/SoBeWFF.accdb;" +
            "Persist Security Info=False";

        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Dishes";

        adapter.SelectCommand = command;

        try
        {
            adapter.Fill(dataset, "Dishes");
        }
        catch (OleDbException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error occured while connecting to database.");
           // Application.Exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post what exception you are getting?

Comment: Without exception error, is hard to understand!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following connection string. (Close the MS-Access/database file if it is opened)

```
connection.ConnectionString =@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\SoBeWFF.accdb";
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my post!  Unfortunately that did not help... I'm getting the following exception at adapter.fill(dataset, "Dishes"):   'The invocation of the constructor on type 'SoBeWFF.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '3' and line position '9'.